# Python Code TypeError Need Assistance Please

Tags: python

Create a program that inputs the amount of hours worked and the hourly rate, and output the pay. NOTE: Every hour over 40, they get 1.5x the money.

***Error is in line 22 and 25. I want to round the answer to 2 decimal places but it says "not all arguments converted during string formatting."***

```
# Constants for hours over 40
BONUS_MONEY_HOURS=40.0
BONUS_MONEY_RATE=1.5

# Inputting the hourly rate and amount of hours worked
hourly_rate=float(input("Please enter how much you make per hour: "))
hours_worked=float(input("Please enter how many hours worked: "))

# Formulas for calculating the amount paid
hours_under_40=float(hourly_rate*hours_worked)
hours_over_40=float(hours_worked-BONUS_MONEY_HOURS)
bonus_money=float(hours_over_40*BONUS_MONEY_RATE)
bonus_plus_normal=float(bonus_money+hours_under_40)

# Outputting the amount paid from different inputs
if hours_worked > 0 and hours_worked < BONUS_MONEY_HOURS:
    print "You get paid $.2f"%hours_under_40

elif hours_worked > 0 and hours_worked > BONUS_MONEY_HOURS:
    print "You get paid $.2f"%bonus_plus_normal

elif hours_worked < 0:
    print "Invalid input. "

elif hourly_rate < 0:
    print "Invalid input. "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $%.2f instead of $.2f   You need the % in there otherwise it's not a formatting character.   Also, looks like your program can't handle the situation where someone works exactly 40 hours, which is slightly common.  : )

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [format](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) method.

```
print "You get paid ${0:.2f}.".format(bonus_plus_normal)
```

Comment: It says "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'"

Comment: @BalkarnGill what version of python are you using?